# Need the standard "gtk-color-scheme" for ambiance

Tags: themes, gtk, ambiance

I have messed up my `gtk-color-scheme` for ambiance. Could anybody please give me the standard `gtk-color-scheme` of ambiance?

I have tried to Google for it, but couldn't find it.

It is the first line (or lines) in: `/usr/share/themes/ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to set things back the way they were, at least for Ambiance and Radiance, is to run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall light-themes
```

This will simply restore the Ambiance and Radiance themes to the version that is in the repos.

Also, for the future, it may be better to copy over whichever theme you plan to modify to the `~/.themes` hidden subfolder in your home folder. Then, do whatever you want there. (If `~/.themes` doesn't exist, just create it.) The advantage is that you have the original as a backup and don't need `sudo` to edit any files in `~/.themes`.

Comment: I had to delete/move the /usr/share/themes/Ambiance folder first and then reinstal + unity restart